# locust.exe does not open on Windows 10

Tags: python, locust

I have installed python 2.7.14 on my system (win 10, 64bit). I have also installed locust and set all env variables but when I click on `Locust.exe` the application opens, but immediately closes again.

Answer (score 1):

> but when i click on the Locust.exe

you don't click on anything to launch Locust... you invoke it from the command line, and pass it the name of the locust file you created:

```
$ locust -f my_locust_file.py --host=http://example.com
```

Once launched, you load the web interface in your browser to control execution:
https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#open-up-locust-s-web-interface

You should read the docs:
https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#start-locust